# Linux Basic Shell for all users

Tags: linux, shell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to restrict the users' shell allowing to execute shell programs](https://serverfault.com/questions/89778/how-to-restrict-the-users-shell-allowing-to-execute-shell-programs)

I used to access this Ubuntu 8.04 server that had a very limited Shell. For instance you couldn't key up,down shell history, you couldn't tab guess commands, etc.

I would like to customized the Ssell inv for my users that ssh into my server, but how?

Comment: Your question seems unrelated to the first paragraph.  In addition, you don't provide any details on your server or its setup.  Unless your server is the Ubuntu 8.04 machine, but the way it's worded this doesn't sound like the case.

Comment: use `chsh(1)` to change the login shell of user's accounts

Comment: Also, probably better suited for http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: Do you want to set up fully functional shell for all your users who login by ssh? Set their shell to /bin/bash then. So they will get auto-completion, command history, etc. What's their current shell? You can see it in /etc/passwd file.

Answer (score 4):

The terminology you are looking for is [Restricted Shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_shell). There are a number of ways to implement restrictions, depending on what you need. One easy approach is to run [Bash in restricted mode](http://linuxandfriends.com/2008/09/07/bash-restricted-shell/).

Answer (score 3):

The shell started by ssh is the users' login shell. It is set via the login shell entry of the passwd file/database (when you don't do anything fancy, it's in /etc/passwd and can be modified by chsh). The shell you describe sounds very much like the basic /bin/sh that is also used in script execution.