# Limitied Shell for users - Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, shell

At my old job we had a Ubuntu 8.04 server that we SSH into. The shell was very limited (no bash history, can not tab predict commands, etc). Is there a config file to do things like that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to restrict the users' shell allowing to execute shell programs](http://serverfault.com/questions/89778/how-to-restrict-the-users-shell-allowing-to-execute-shell-programs)

Comment: I don't care about executing shell programs, I care about the shell environment.

Comment: From what you describe, the shell was `/bin/sh` (intended for script execution) rather than the more usual `/bin/bash` (intended for both script execution and interactive use). [MikeyB's answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/316097/limitied-shell-for-users-ubuntu/316111#316111) tells you how to change a user's shell to `/bin/sh`, but why would you want to? What do you hope to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You're just trying to remove features? Change the shell using `chsh` and use /bin/sh instead of bash.